# Add HTML block via Plugin on Joomla article manager

Tags: joomla

I am new to Joomla development. I wanna add one HTML table to Article Manager page (when creating or editing articles). How can I do that ? I tried to look it up everywhere but cannot find any solution. Only thing I found is to add form fields via .xml.

I only want that block to appear on article manager page, not on front end for all the users.

Can someone point me to right direction please.

Answer (score 1):

The TinyMCE editor ships with the ability to make mini html snippets and insert them in articles or other edit screens.  You need to go to the plugin and switch to Extended mode.

THe plugin itself has samples. The new ones for the updated TinyMCE that is in J 3.2 are a little different in design but still very easy.
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/master/media/editors/tinymce/templates

Comment: Hi Elin, thanks for the help but that's not what I wanted. I do not want some HTML block to appear in an article. Instead I want one PHP/HTML block to appear somewhere on "article manager page", not in the editor. Basically, I wanna integrate Content Scoring service with Joomla, that will show score of you content. That score should only be visible to whoever have access to edit that article. If I have not made my self clear do let me know, I will provide screenshots. Thanks

Comment: You said you want to add "one html table"  but now it sounds more like you want to show a value associated with an article.  Where is this value being stored?

Comment: The value is coming from the API. Everytime user wishes to view article, API makes the call send article content and get receives Json decoded response that needs to display to author only.

Comment: So why don't you just do an override with a trigger to call your plugin that gets and render the data, just like you would on the front end?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this (if I understand correctly) is to create a Custom HTML module in Module Manager with the module position as "snippet" or something similar.

Wherever you wish to reuse the code in an article, use the {loadposition snippet} syntax.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the help but that's not what I wanted. I do not want some HTML block to appear in an article. Instead I want one PHP/HTML block to appear somewhere on "article manager page", not in the editor. Basically, I wanna integrate Content Scoring service with Joomla, that will show score of you content. That score should only be visible to whoever have access to edit that article. If I have not made my self clear do let me know, I will provide screenshots. Thanks